# Proving regular expression identity

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

For regular expressions $r$ and $s$ prove:
$$(r^*s^*)^*=(r+s)^*$$

I guess I have to prove the equality of sets $(R^*S^*)^* = \left\{ x_1^{n_1}y_1^{m_1}x_2^{n_2}y_2^{m_2}... \mid n_i,m_j \in \mathbb{N_0},x_i \in R, y_j \in S \right\}$ and $(R \cup S)^* = \left\{ x_1^{n_1}x_2^{n_2}x_3^{n_3}... \mid n_i \in 
\mathbb{N_0},x_i \in R \cup S \right\}$
This seems simple enough.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of: [Proof for formal languages](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136933/525384).